# Set up Socket Client always listen data

Tags: java, android, sockets, serversocket

I can set up client `Socket` to send request to server (`sendData()` method) and read the received message (`readData()` method) correctly, but I only received message each time I send the request to server by using `MOBILE_REQUEST` string, through these codes:

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        mSocket = new Socket(
                // PC Ip is 192.168.1.199 
                // It is the other device, Not be local host : 127.0.0.1
                Pas.pas.getPcIP(), 17001);

        DataOutputStream mDos = new DataOutputStream(mSocket.getOutputStream());

        String RESPONSE = null;
        String MOBILE_BLOCK = "MobileBlock#";

         // Converting collected data in byte array into String.
         RESPONSE = sendData(mDos, MOBILE_BLOCK);

         /**
           * The result response from PC app in here
           */
         // Log : response - #WindowsResp#192.168.1.199#
         Log.i("", "response '" + RESPONSE + "'");

        }

    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        IS_SOCKET_TIME_OUT = true;

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ConnectException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

`sendData()` method - Client send the request to server and wait to get response data - String data.

```
private String sendData(DataOutputStream mDos, String MOBILE_REQUEST) {
    try {
        // Log : MOBILE_REQUEST.getBytes() - [B@82f10f8
        mDos.write(MOBILE_REQUEST.getBytes());

        // todo I should set this sleep, bcs TCP has delay time, 
        // so i need set the delay time for client should receive data
        // otherwise, sometimes I did not receive anything
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Log : #WindowsResp#192.168.1.199#
        return new String(readData(mSocket));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

`readData()` method - Read data after received from server.

```
public static byte[] readData(Socket mSocket) {
    /* Since data are accepted as byte, all of them will be collected in the
        following byte array which initialised with accepted data length. */
    DataInputStream mDis = null;
    try {
        mDis = new DataInputStream(mSocket.getInputStream());

        // Log : mDis.available() - 23
        byte[] data = new byte[mDis.available()];

        // Collecting data into byte array
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            data[i] = mDis.readByte();

        // Log : data - [B@30c044a4
        return data;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

What I want is every time server send to my socket client the message by clicking button, the socket client should receive it. But in above codes, it's not.

Please help me how to set up socket client always listen from server?

p/s : Or do I need set up `ServerSocket`? If use `ServerSocket` I cannot use same port, right? Because when I open `ServerSocket` for listen first (ex. at port 17001), I can not use client socket to send request via port 17001 because that port is already used.

**UPDATED**

The way server (PC app - laptop device) send to client (Mobile device - Android) is via Socket TCP, through these steps :

1 - Client (Android device) set up TCP socket connection to Server (PC app) (this connection never closed until exit app in `onDestroy()` method).

2 - Client send request to server, ex. `MOBILE_REQUEST = "MobileID#MobileIP#"`

3 - Server received the request from client, It replied to client via Socket connection, actually client received data correctly. ex. `"WindowsRep#WindowsIP"`

This way not work for me, even socket TCP connection not closed, and `getInputStream()` not shut down yet. In this case :

Server send string data to client via Socket connection, client received data correctly.

What I want is every time "Server send string data to client via Socket connection, client received data correctly". But in my case, client only receive data after sent request to server.

**C# Server**

Server socket

```
IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint("192.168.1.199", 17001);
svSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
svSocket.Bind(ipe);
```

Server Send data

```
string data_send = "#WBroad#" + "192.168.1.199" + "#";
byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data_send);
c.ClientSocket.Send(byteData);
```

Comment: Where are (1) the `readData()` method (2) the peer code that reads what this code writes and (3) the peer code that writes what `readData()` reads? Your final paragraph about port 10000 doesn't make sense.

Comment: Where are (2) the peer code that reads what this code writes and (3) the peer code that writes what readData() reads? And what is difficult to understand about this? And what makes you think it's correct when the system doesn't work? If you want help here you must provide all relevant information.

Comment: Where is the peer code? This is a client. The peer is a server. Where is its code? Third time of asking. NB Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code.

Comment: `The peer is a server` Oh i see now. Server is c# code. The Server is PC app. I don't have code to post here. But iOs app can always listen & and receive data from PC app everytime PC app send is correctly. In my case, Android app always be Client, and it only receive the message after send request to server (PC app). What I want is can receive message from server even not send the request to server. You understand me now?

Comment: So you need to tell us how the server sends the data. Lines? Length-word prefix? XML? ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you haven't posted the sending code it is impossible to tell why you're not receiving data, but here is a quick critique of what you have posted:

```
 //            mSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
```

You've commmented this out, but it would be pointless to call this method now. You would have to construct the socket as `new Socket()`, with no parameters, then call this method, then call `connect()`. And as you aren't providing a source port or IP address to be re-used, it would still be pointless.

```
        byte[] data = new byte[mDis.available()];
```

This is a complete misuse of `available()`. It does not provide a message length. See the Javadoc. There is no reason to believe that whatever data has arrived at this point, *if any,* is a complete message, or only one message. If you want messages you won't get any help from TCP: you will have to implement them yourself. As your protocol appears to be text-based I suggest you just use lines and `readLine()`, with `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter` instead of the `DataInput/OutputStreams`. And construct those once for the life of the socket, not once per application message, otherwise you will lose data.

```
        // Collecting data into byte array
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            data[i] = mDis.readByte();
```

The **huge** problem with this is that it won't block, because, most of the time, `available()` will be zero, so this method will do nothing except return an empty `byte[]` array.

In any case this is entirely equivalent to `mDis.readFully(data);`, only several times less efficient, but you shouldn't be doing this anyway: see above.

```
    return data;    
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
```

This is poor practice. You should let the `IOException` be thrown by this method and let the caller deal with it.

```
        mDos.write(MOBILE_REQUEST.getBytes());
```

See above. This should include a line terminator, a length-word prefix, or some other way of delimiting the message.

```
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This sleep is literally a complete and utter waste of time. And space. Remove it. Sleeping in networking code is just cargo-cult programming.

```
        return new String(readData(mSocket));
```

This will throw a `NullPointerException` if `readData()` returns `null`, which it does if there was an `IOException`, which is another reason to let that method propagate that exception instead of catching it internally and returning null.

```
private boolean splitData(int mobile_send_request_case, String DATA) {
```

This method is entirely irrelevant to the problem and should not have been posted.

> Or do I need set up `ServerSocket`?

No. Why do you think that?

> If use `ServerSocket` I cannot use same port, right?

Wrong.

> Because when I open `ServerSocket` for listen first (ex. at port 17001), I can not use client socket to send request via port 17001 because that port is already used.

Wrong again. It isn't.

As I said above, it's impossible to help you further when you don't post all the relevant code, but there's enough wrong with this already that you really need to start again.

Comment: Mmmmm... i just see this thread. Glad you saw it before. That was a lot of writing. For me you did the job. Have a rest for the rest of the day ;-).

Comment: @EJP : But i want to know, the socket was set up as client always listen until I called `socket.close()` right? So it should receive message everytime server sent right?

Comment: @MirrorTowers Correct. The socket stays open until you close it. Your question?

Comment: No no, I know the socket stay open until I close it. But if client socket always listen, my question is why I can not receive the string data from server every time server clicked button in PC app. It's strange right? I never close socket until exit app.

Comment: I've already answered that, at great length, above, and been complimented by @greenapps for so doing. I can also show you how to code the solution, but not until you provide a plausible, intelligible, and implementable specification as to how the messages in this protocol are delimited. You've now been asked for that four or five times and you have so far completely failed to oblige.